# How to insert different picture in glsgroupheading glossary

Tags: graphics, glossaries

How to insert picture in `glsgroupheading` glossary so that each parent is talking a different.

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec}


% Headers and footers
\fancyhead[RE]{\thepage \textsf{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\thepage \textsf{\rightmark}}
\fancyfoot[]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}

\pagestyle{fancy}

% For testing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}


\makeglossaries

% The optional argument is in case you can't use the name as a label    
\newcommand{\dict}[4][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}%
  {%
    name={#2},%
    symbol=#3,%
    description=#4,%
    #1%
  }%
}

\newglossarystyle{dict}%
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{\end{multicols}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \section*{##1}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\end{multicols}}%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \markboth{##2}{##2}%
    \par\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}%
    \textbf{\textsf{##2}} \textit{- ##4 -} ##3%
  }%
}%
\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
   \dict{zero}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
   \dict{adhesive}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
   \dict{adhere}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
   \dict{adhesion}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
   \dict{adjacent}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
   \dict{adjust}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
   \dict{main}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
   \dict{material}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
   \dict{more}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
   \dict{zebra}{n}{\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum}
   \dict{adherence}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
   \dict{adjective}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
   \dict{adjoin}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
   \dict{mathematic}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
   \dict{adjourn}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
   \dict{adjournment}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
   \dict{adjunt}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
   \dict{adequate}{n}{\lipsum[1]}              

\begin{document}


\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=dict]
\end{document}
```

(I mean nothing is insert different images for Leaders. For example, the head of a picture and the word parent is talking to a different picture.).

I understand I will put a picture:
[image]

Comment: You cannot attach it. Copy the example and paste it into your question. Then select it and use the `{}` button or ctrl+k to format it as a code block. Right now, I don't understand your question but your minimal example should help to make it clearer. Use the `edit` link at the bottom of your question to add in your code.

Comment: Oh. Yes my friend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not certain I've understood your question. I'm guessing from the code, really, so just let me know if this is nothing to do with it and I can delete this answer.

## Current Guess: Illustrated Headings

Do you want something like this?

[image: A is for apple]
[image: M is for pi]
[image: Z is for zebra crossing]

The following assumes that your illustrations are named by the letters to which they correspond e.g. `A.png`, `M.jpg` or `Z.pdf`. The solution isn't ideal as it puts the picture into the section heading. However, perhaps that is OK for such a specialist use, given that these are not being added to the contents or featured in the headers/footers etc.

Code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec}

% Headers and footers
\fancyhead[RE]{\textsf{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage{} \textsf{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textsf{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsf{\leftmark} \thepage{}}
\fancyfoot[]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% For testing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% The optional argument is in case you can't use the name as a label
\newcommand{\dict}[4][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}%
  {%
    name={#2},%
    symbol=#3,%
    description=#4,%
    #1%
  }%
}

\newglossarystyle{dict}%
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{\end{multicols}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \section*{##1 \includegraphics[height=\baselineskip]{##1}}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\end{multicols}}%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \markboth{##2}{##2}%
    \par\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}%
    \textbf{\textsf{##2}} \textit{- ##4 -} ##3%
  }%
}%
\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\dict{zero}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
\dict{adhesive}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
\dict{adhere}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
\dict{adhesion}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
\dict{adjacent}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
\dict{adjust}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
\dict{main}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
\dict{material}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
\dict{more}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
\dict{zebra}{n}{\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum}
\dict{adherence}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
\dict{adjective}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
\dict{adjoin}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
\dict{mathematic}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
\dict{adjourn}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
\dict{adjournment}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
\dict{adjunt}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
\dict{adequate}{n}{\lipsum[1]}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=dict]
\end{document}
```

## Original Guess: Dictionary-Style Headers

Do you want something like this?

[image: dictionary headings]

This provides something like dictionary-style headers for the document, so that the entry headings for the first and last entries on each page appear in the left and right of the header for that page.

If so, you need to specify the left and right header for each of even and odd pages, adding the page number as appropriate. (I've assumed the page number should always be on the outside as that is the usual place.)

In case that is of some use, here's the code:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage[bf,sf,center]{titlesec}

% Headers and footers
\fancyhead[RE]{\textsf{\leftmark}}
\fancyhead[LE]{\thepage{} \textsf{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[LO]{\textsf{\rightmark}}
\fancyhead[RO]{\textsf{\leftmark} \thepage{}}
\fancyfoot[]{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

% For testing
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[xindy]{glossaries}
\makeglossaries

% The optional argument is in case you can't use the name as a label
\newcommand{\dict}[4][]{%
  \newglossaryentry{#2}%
  {%
    name={#2},%
    symbol=#3,%
    description=#4,%
    #1%
  }%
}

\newglossarystyle{dict}%
{%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}{}{\end{multicols}}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryheader}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupheading}[1]{%
    \section*{##1}%
    \begin{multicols}{2}%
  }%
  \renewcommand*{\glsgroupskip}{\end{multicols}}%
  \renewcommand{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \markboth{##2}{##2}%
    \par\vspace{0.25\baselineskip}%
    \textbf{\textsf{##2}} \textit{- ##4 -} ##3%
  }%
}%
\renewcommand*{\glossarysection}[2][]{}
\dict{zero}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
\dict{adhesive}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
\dict{adhere}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
\dict{adhesion}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
\dict{adjacent}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
\dict{adjust}{n}{\lipsum[6]}
\dict{main}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
\dict{material}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
\dict{more}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
\dict{zebra}{n}{\lipsum \lipsum \lipsum}
\dict{adherence}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
\dict{adjective}{n}{\lipsum[1]}
\dict{adjoin}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
\dict{mathematic}{n}{\lipsum[2]}
\dict{adjourn}{n}{\lipsum[3]}
\dict{adjournment}{n}{\lipsum[4]}
\dict{adjunt}{n}{\lipsum[5]}
\dict{adequate}{n}{\lipsum[1]}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=dict]
\end{document}
```

Comment: My freind. i edited question and put a picture for understand my mean.Please help for this purpose.

Comment: I'm still guessing, really. However, I've updated with my current guess.

Comment: Oh thank you very much @cfr. I Mean Current Guess: Illustrated Headings. you answersd Excellent.

Comment: @A.ata Excellent! Good to know. I'll leave the original bit, if you don't mind, in case somebody else can use it.

Comment: excuse me. Sorry If I misbehave.

Comment: @A.ata If anything I said suggested I thought that you did so, please accept my apologies. I certainly did not mean to suggest that you said anything at all bad or inappropriate. You have nothing whatsoever to be sorry for! (At least, nothing I know of ;).) Perhaps something got lost (or gained) in translation?

Comment: Please Solve this problem. I use your code for persian glossary and appeared Error File `آ' not found. \glsgroupheading{آ}.

Comment: @A.ata Please, ask a new question with a link to this one. RTL typesetting introduces complications and my solution here is certainly not going to work because TeX is not going to like the file names when they are no longer ASCII. So a different approach will be needed for this kind of case.